# + string not supported on GET method PHP? any solution to show + string on php Get Method

Tags: php, helper

Symbol `+` in string not supported on `GET` method PHP? Any solution to show `+` string on php `Get` Method.

Any Solution ?
when I Submit a Form ( `Get` )
space are Change as `+` string
so I can't submit a form when text include `+` Symbol
any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

What about `urlencode()` in PHP or `encodeURIComponent()` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Special chars are also supported in get method. Don't let to distract you the url because if you use non ascii or special chars then it will change to html entity.

Try to print out the get method's value and you will see it is the same as the sent string.

Answer (score 0):

try to something like that

```
$temp=$_GET['phone_no'];
$no='+'.str_replace(' ','',$temp);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.